# Steam Summer Sale minigame - gold coins

Tags: steam-monster-game

What do the gold steam coins do? I've been seeing them but haven't been able to figure out what it actually does, or if they do anything at all.

[image: gold steam coin]

Comment: This is the URL for the coin itself, although I don't know what causes it to be displayed, maybe it will help someone who wants to hack further :)  http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/assets/minigame/towerattack/steam_coin_large.png?v=d1acb67394826930890eb4ee121d72ba

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Giant Coin on the screen indicates that someone has activated the "Metal Detector" ability. You can see this by checking the right hand side ability list immediately after this occurs. Other abilities/items have similar but different effects on the battlefied area. For example, blue pluses indicate the medic ability has been activated, and green sparkles indicate good luck charms are active.

Comment: The "Treasure!" item will also activate the metal detector, but has additional side effects for the user.